# Add Hyperlink at property pane description area

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, spfx-custom-property-pane

I am building an SPFX web-part and I want to put my company URL in the description of the property pane, like in the Microsoft docs snippet:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/integrate-with-property-pane

But I cant find the way to do this and I googled for hours. Description always return the string and not the link.

Code below (already tried to override the description property to assume HTML but without success:

```
protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
return {
  pages: [
    {
      header: {
        description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
      },
      displayGroupsAsAccordion: true,
      groups: [
        
        {
          groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
          isCollapsed: true,
          groupFields: [
            PropertyPaneTextField('siteurl', {
              label: strings.SiteUrl
            }),
            PropertyPaneTextField('listname', {
              label: strings.List
            })

          ]
        },
        {
          groupName: strings.NewsDefinitions,
          isCollapsed: true,
          groupFields: [
            PropertyPaneTextField('iconText', {
              label: strings.IconText
            }),
            PropertyPaneSlider('sliderproperty', {
              label: strings.Speed,
              min: 5,
              max: 60,
              value: 60,
              showValue: true,
              step: 1
            }),

          ]

        },
        {
          groupName: strings.ColorDefinitions,
          isCollapsed: true,
          groupFields: [
            PropertyFieldColorPicker('iconTextColor', {
              label: strings.IconTextColor,
              selectedColor: this.properties.iconTextColor,
              onPropertyChange: this.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged,
              properties: this.properties,
              disabled: false,
              isHidden: false,
              alphaSliderHidden: false,
              style: PropertyFieldColorPickerStyle.Full,
              iconName: 'Precipitation',
              key: 'colorFieldId'
            }),

            PropertyFieldColorPicker('mainColor', {
              label: strings.MainColor,
              selectedColor: this.properties.mainColor,
              onPropertyChange: this.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged,
              properties: this.properties,
              disabled: false,
              isHidden: false,
              alphaSliderHidden: false,
              style: PropertyFieldColorPickerStyle.Full,
              iconName: 'Precipitation',
              key: 'colorFieldId'
            }),
            PropertyFieldColorPicker('innerColor', {
              label: strings.InnerColor,
              selectedColor: this.properties.innerColor,
              onPropertyChange: this.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged,
              properties: this.properties,
              disabled: false,
              isHidden: false,
              alphaSliderHidden: false,
              style: PropertyFieldColorPickerStyle.Full,
              iconName: 'Precipitation',
              key: 'innercolorFieldId'
            })
          ]
        },
        {
          isCollapsed:false,
          groupFields: [
            PropertyFieldLinkWithCallout('fakeProp', {
              calloutTrigger: CalloutTriggers.Click,
              key: 'linkWithCalloutFieldId',
              calloutContent: React.createElement('p', {}, 'Click the link to open a new page with Application Terms & Conditions'),
              calloutWidth: 200,
              text: 'Terms & Conditions',
              href: 'https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-property-controls',
              target: '_blank'
            })
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

}

[image]

Comment: have you tried it? I see that only strings are allowed. Here's the type class. export declare interface IPropertyPanePageHeader {
    /**
     * Header to display.
     */
    description: string;
    /**
     * Image url for the background image.
     */
    image?: string;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to do. Just have to add a `React.createElement()` and it renders with a hyperlink.

```
protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    if(this.properties.listOrDocument==="3"){
      this.isList=false;
    }

    return {
      pages: [
        {
            header:{
              description:React.createElement("div",{},["Developed by ",React.createElement("a",{href:'https://www.torpedo.pt'},"Torpedo")]) 
            },
(..)
```

The best way is to assign multiple elements to variables and then put inside the array where we want to render them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Ganesh, I don't think it works. I see that only strings are allowed. Here's the type class. export declare interface IPropertyPanePageHeader {
    /**
     * Header to display.
     */
    description: string;
    /**
     * Image url for the background image.
     */
    image?: string;
}

Comment: Hi Ganesh, sorry for the late reply.. Yes it did work but i had to change the type for IPropertyPaneField (added image above)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes looking for this years later, I found a way to do this using PropertyPaneLink

```
  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description:"View the Azure DevOps Board for details on usage and configuration" 
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: "Configure this Webpart",
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('listNameProperty', {
                  description: "xxx",
                  label: "List URL"
                }),
                PropertyPaneLink('linkProperty', {
                href: 'http://www.google.com',
                text: 'Click to view usage and configuration details',
                target: '_blank'})
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

Scroll down to the PropertyPaneLink section for example: https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/02/sharepoint-framework-web-part-properties-button-toggle-slider.html

Comment: +1 for not adding an entire framework like React to solve a tiny issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@pnp/spfx-property-controls` which has `PropertyFieldLinkWithCallout` control.

This control generates a link control with a callout.

Example code:

1. Import the following modules to your component:

```
import { CalloutTriggers } from '@pnp/spfx-property-controls/lib/Callout';
import { PropertyFieldLinkWithCallout } from '@pnp/spfx-property-controls/lib/PropertyFieldLinkWithCallout';
```

2. Add the custom property control to the groupFields of the web part property pane configuration:

```
PropertyFieldLinkWithCallout('fakeProp', {
  calloutTrigger: CalloutTriggers.Click,
  key: 'linkWithCalloutFieldId',
  calloutContent: React.createElement('p', {}, 'Click the link to open a new page with Application Terms & Conditions'),
  calloutWidth: 200,
  text: 'Terms & Conditions',
  href: 'https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-property-controls',
  target: '_blank'
})
```

**Reference**: [PropertyFieldLinkWithCallout control](https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-property-controls/controls/PropertyFieldLinkWithCallout/)

Comment: Hi Ganesh, thanks for the fast response.. that i've already tried and indeed it shows the link but i wanted something like the link i gave from Microsoft https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/basics/integrate-with-property-pane .. the first image where you can see the "learn more" link is at the header of the property pane. Every time i tried to put some 'a' tag it shows as a string ie (<a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a> it should show only "Google" but it shows the html tag..)

Comment: This is because the header expects the string and it treats it as a string only. So, instead of giving description to header, keep it blank and then use this control at the top of property pane. it should give you the same feel as the image you are referring to.

Comment: is there some way to avoid this property of getting in the accordion group?? 

https://imgur.com/a/xsQ9298 i dont want the empty group name neither the collapse arrow

Comment: I think it is showing like this because you are using multiple `groups` inside your property pane. Need to check if we can remove the collapse arrow. Can you please add the code you are using inside `getPropertyPaneConfiguration()`?

Comment: added my whole property pane config..

Comment: I don't think there is any configuration property for group which will hide that arrow. however you can keep that particular group expanded using `isCollapsed: false` (as you already did). Check the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/sp-property-pane/ipropertypanegroup). Maybe if you can hide it using custom CSS in your code, you need to check it.

Comment: Or check how the Author name is added in the property pane in [this](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) sample webpart on GitHub.

Comment: just post the answer.. it was quite easy.. after i found the solution ^^ thanks for your help tho

Answer (score 0):

How we can overwrite IPropertyPanePageHeader interface, even if i try to declare the interface in the webpart.ts file, its still refering to index-internal.ts file for the IpropertyPanePageHEader interface. can someone suggest? [image]

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/120113)